# How to do a double update

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i have a page that uses validation (value must be set ) and this is usually updated via growl, however i also want to use the same button to if the validation has been passed successfully update a datatable

what is the best way to do this ?
  Select how you would like the data sorted :

```
                <br></br>
            </h:panelGrid>
            <p:commandButton value="#{bundle.buttonSearch}" action="#{bean.advancedSearch}" update=":growl" icon ="ui-icon-search" />

            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            <h:panelGroup id="group">
                <p:dataTable id="UserTableSearch"
                             rowKey="#{bean.userSearchResults}"
                             rendered="#{facesContext.postback}"
                             widgetVar="UserTableSearch" 
                             paginator="true" 
                             rows="10"
                             value="#{bean.userSearchResults}"
                             var="item"
                             emptyMessage="No results found."
                             scrollable="true">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can include two or more component ids in the `update` attribute of your `<p:commandButton>`.

```
<p:commandButton value="#{bundle.buttonSearch}" action="#{bean.advancedSearch}"
    update="growl group" icon ="ui-icon-search" />
```

Answer (score 0):

added an onlick command to the command button

```
<p:commandButton value="#{bundle.buttonSearch}" action="#{bean.advancedSearch}" onclick="update growl" update="group" icon ="ui-icon-search" />
```

now all working :)

Comment: Thanks i didn't know i could do that, that is a much better answer